# hidden service + reverse proxy not working

Tags: configuration, onion-services, proxy

i'm trying to set up a hidden service for an existing webserver that is behind a reverse proxy and i'm unable to get it work. i had no problems creating hidden services on servers with no reverse proxy so i thought that could be the issue. the reverse proxy mainly just takes care of https redirect.

following the tor project instructions:
http://3gldbgtv5e4god56.onion/onion-services/setup/

`torsocks curl http://3gldbgtv5e4god56.onion` from the server works, so tor is working.

i tried letting tor connect to either the reverse proxy or the backend, matching the torrc `HiddenServicePort` entry to a virtual host on either server. when i load the onion address in a browser, i get this error:

> Invalid Onionsite Address
>
> [x] Browser | Network | Onionsite
>
> The provided onionsite address is invalid. Please check that you entered it correctly.
>
> Details: 0xF6 — The provided .onion address is invalid. This error is returned due to one of the following reasons: the address checksum doesn't match, the ed25519 public key is invalid, or the encoding is invalid.

in the `tor/notices.log`
i see this error:

`[warn] Could not mmap file "/var/lib/tor/cached-microdescs": Permission denied`

`[err] Couldn't map file that we just wrote to /var/lib/tor/cached-microdescs`

right after `Bootstrapped 0%: Starting`, but then it finishes bootstrapping with no further problems.

i'm not sure if either error message is reliably pointing to my issue.

so:

- can i test my new address any other way? [surely its fine?]
- can i test that tor is able to receive incoming connections?
- wd this error maybe show up if the address was ok but not correctly configured to connect to a service?
- are any extra steps involved when configuring a hidden service with a reverse proxy?
- could it be a ports issue if my server is already running a clearnet service?
- is there a likely 'translation' of this error message?

i also just tried setting up a new hidden service from scratch, and then a new server block on the reverse proxy server, but now just pointing to a new webroot with a dummy index.html (which i can access locally with `http://127.0.0.1:80`), and i still get the same error.

EDIT:

- i'm installing LTS tor from debian stable. after installing i have enabled/run/restarted it with systemctl. i've not set 'run as daemon'
- permissions on `/var/lib/tor` are `drwx--S--- 4 debian-tor debian-tor`, and on the `cached-microdescs` they are `-rw------- 1 debian-tor debian-tor`

**EDIT 2 as per steve's request for more detail:**

- i'm not running tor from the commandline, no. just `systemctl enable/restart`
- i'm not in a container. i am on an arm box, no vm.
- torrc looks like

```
Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/onion/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

- the server block i set up looks like

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name xyxyxyxzzzz.onion;
    root /var/www/onion;
    access_log off;

    index index.html index.html index.nginx-debian.html;    
}
```

- i got my onion address as recommended by the docs: `sudo cat /var/lib/tor/onion/hostname`.
- i don't actually know what mmapping a file is. the permissions for dirs + files are defaults on fresh tor install.

**update**

- `Tor version 0.3.5.10.`
- an onion my tor created (random/not configured in the webserver): `uj23izqtsljsbsqrn2qfyvxl6t22az5nthhneufwjnutajd4pe2c43yd.onion`
- also, if i create a random onion with no webserver config on a different box, i don't get the same error. if the torrc conf is for an open port (eg 80), i get a 404, and if i put a dead/closed port in the torrc file, i get the standard firefox "Unable to connect" error.

Comment: Deleted my answer since it doesn't seem relevant anymore. So there still isn't enough information here for me to understand what's going wrong. Why can't you mmap a file, are you run in a container or restricted environment? You're not running `tor` on the command line right, only through the systemd service? Can you post all uncommented lines in your torrc file? Can you post the server block you're using on your reverse proxy? Where are you getting the onion URL from? The Tor Browser says it's not in the correct format.

Comment: re the mmap error, system logs reported apparmor was blocking tor from doing what it wanted. i disabled apparmor, restarted tor, got no log errors, but still no dice w the hidden service.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're doing everything right, so I'm not sure what's going wrong. There are no other errors/warnings in the log? What's the output of `tor --version`? And can you post an onion address (either the one you're trying to set up or a new one) that causes the browser to give the "Invalid Onionsite Address" error?

Comment: i suspect i have something v basic messed up, which will be embarrassing when i find out. but it is also v helpful to confirm that i'm at least try to set it more or less in the right way. @Steve

Comment: So your onion address is not a valid onion address. I made a small python script you can test [here](https://paste.debian.net/1151964/) if you'd like. If you comment out your address, you can see that the example address works fine. I'm really not sure why tor would give you an invalid address. Maybe try deleting your onion service (delete the keys from your hidden service directory) and let tor choose new ones? If the new one is also incorrect, then this problem is very strange.

Comment: @Steve thx a lot for that. so all the onions it creates are invalid. i tried deleting the keys to no avail, have also previously tried purging/reinstalling tor and creating new onions. with v2 onions i dont receive that error. might try that or else will have to relent.

Comment: v2 works. maybe my old arm box is too old and grey for v3. thx for helping me past my block.

Comment: That's really strange :( You could probably make a v3 onion on one computer and copy the keys to your arm box if you wanted.

Comment: I am having the same problem here and this is also on an arm box. armv5tel to be precise. Could you share what is the architecture of your box

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisParis mine is armv5tel also. i thought i was the only person left on the planet still using it. :) i ended up simply going with v2 onion. (copying a v3 onion from another box also didn't work.)

Comment: I tested the same pair of keys on the armv5tel, an x86_64 and a raspberry pi (armhf). The arm5 generates a different onion address that does not work. The other 2 generates the same onion and it works. -> an arch related bug. I reported it with Debian